# Preventdefault not working for left click, working fine for middle and right

Tags: jquery, preventdefault, mousedown

I've wrote the below code to show a `jQuery-UI dialog` box popup when user clicks (left, middle or right) on external links. It is working fine for middle and right click but on left click it's not working correctly (preventDefault fails for left click I guess). I've implemented this [on my site](http://www.technostall.com/samsung-galaxy-ace-plus-s7500-how-to-root-and-install-custom-recovery-image/), you can see the problem there.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('a').filter(function() {
    return this.href.indexOf(location.origin) !== 0;
}).addClass('external');
$(document).on("mousedown", "a.external", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      popUp.start(this);
});

-----------------
-----------------
code for showing popup
-----------------
</script>
```

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle with the issue.

Comment: It's working for left button click, too.

Comment: The link is opening instantly, if you do middle or right click you will notice link doesn't open instantly, it waits for 30 seconds.

Comment: For left click it also open the popout that makes me wait 30 seconds.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox, but I've tested it on Chrome, also.

Comment: Strange, for me when I do left click it opens the link in new tab (both Chrome and FF) and on the previous tab there is popup box with counter. It opens another link after 30 seconds.

Comment: Please be sure that the script isn't cached in browser. Also, put a break point there.

Comment: I have cleared the cache, I asked my friend to check, he said it works for first time but after that it doesn't.

Comment: Let's chat here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31818/chat-with-johnny